# Django Heroku App Crashed can't find "/" or "/favicon.ico"

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

```
2015-11-12T04:16:38.270955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-wildwood-3859.herokuapp.com request_id=c58a387c-7577-46c4-890e-1d3a32d3691b fwd="128.237.130.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2015-11-12T04:16:38.611269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-wildwood-3859.herokuapp.com request_id=fdd8e6ba-4637-4f8e-9d0f-67fef51e7820 fwd="128.237.130.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I am trying to deploy my django app but my app is crashing. I am pretty sure my `requirements.txt` is correct.

Also is there any way to get a more detailed error message than just "app crashed" ?

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn webapps.wsgi --log-file -
```

requirements.txt:

```
altgraph==0.10.2
appnope==0.1.0
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0  
decorator==4.0.4
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.8.6
django-haystack==2.4.1
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
elasticsearch==2.1.0
gnureadline==6.3.3
gunicorn==19.3.0
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
path.py==8.1.2
pbr==1.8.1
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.5
Pillow==3.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
ptyprocess==0.5
py2app==0.7.3
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
static3==0.6.1
urllib3==1.12
virtualenv==13.1.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.1
wheel==0.24.0
whitenoise==2.0.4
```

project structure looks like this

root dir:
projectdir
appdir
manage.py
Procfile

appdir contains
templates
static
media
views.py/models.py etc.

I think my problem is that I need to configure the settings.py and wsgi.py files.

Right now I have this in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and this in my wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webapps.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: Right now i got it to deploy but none of my CSS files are being loaded. I'm trying to figure out what to put in the settings.py and wsgi.py files so that my static files are properly loaded

Comment: Can you please post your req.txt and Procfile and also tell how the project structure is ?